# PHP - Best way to parse array of conditions

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements

I have a PHP array like so:

```
$booleans = array(true, '||', false, '&&', true, '||', false);
```

Now I would now like to convert this array to a condition, e.g.:

```
if(true || false && true || false){

     // Do something

}
else{

    // Do something else

}
```

Preferably, for security reasons, I want to avoid using `eval`.

Is this possible? If so, what is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Using implode() you can convert array into string but how can you use in if condition you have to find some solution(from my point of view not possible)

Comment: You can't just loop over this and apply the operators one by one, from left to right - because that would not take into account, that `&&` binds stronger than `||`. You would need a solution that is able to take into account _operator precedence_.

Comment: @CBroe That is a good point, I did not even this of that. But maybe looping through it is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a finite solution for all operations and precedence, but a direction on how you may resolve it. You can refer to [Shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm)
.

```
$validateExpression = function (array $expression): bool {
    $allowedOperators = ['&&', '||'];
    $values = [];
    $operators = [];
    foreach ($expression as $expr) {
        if (is_bool($expr)) {
            $values[] = $expr;
            continue;
        }
        if (in_array($expr, $allowedOperators)) {
            $operators[] = $expr;
            continue;
        }
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid expression');
    }

    while($operators) {
        $a = array_shift($values);
        $b = array_shift($operators);
        $c = array_shift($values);
        array_unshift($values, match($b) {
            '&&' => $a && $c,
            '||' => $a || $c,
        });
    }

    return reset($values);
};

var_dump($validateExpression([true, '||', false, '&&', true, '||', false]));
var_dump(true || false && true || false);
```

#### Output

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

Comment: Ahh you beat me to it, and you did it efficiently! +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that array is well-formatted and you can use this code:

```php
<?php

function parseArray(array $booleans): bool
{
    $result = false;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($booleans); $i += 2) {
        if ($i + 1 === count($booleans) || $booleans[$i + 1] === '||') {
            $result = $result || $booleans[$i];

            continue;
        }

        $andResult = $booleans[$i];
        while ($booleans[$i + 1] === '&&') {
            $i += 2;

            $andResult = $andResult && $booleans[$i];

            if ($i + 1 === count($booleans)) {
                break;
            }
        }

        $result = $result || $andResult;
    }

    return $result;
}

var_dump(parseArray([false]));
var_dump(parseArray([true]));
var_dump(parseArray([true, '&&', false]));
var_dump(parseArray([true, '&&', true]));
var_dump(parseArray([true, '||', false]));
var_dump(parseArray([false, '||', false]));
var_dump(parseArray([false, '||', false, '&&', true, '||', false]));
var_dump(parseArray([true, '||', false, '&&', true, '||', false]));
```

First of all collapse all `&&` because they have higher priority, then calculate all `||`

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit weird to me why you'd want to do that. But for complex repetitive validations you may use functions.

Like so:

```
function validate($params) {
    return true || false && true || false; // Maybe you'd want to use $params in there at some point?
}
```

Then you can use it in an if statement

```
if(validate($myParam)){
     // Do something
}
else{
    // Do something else
}
```

I still don't understand WHY you'd want what you have shown in your question but I think you may be able to accomplish what you want with a similar type of function(s).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, this does not parse the array, which is the main point of my question.

Comment: @Ood As I've said, I do not understand why you'd want to parse conditions FROM an array, I mean you could use `if (array[0])` for the true/false but you can't get the `||` in there. Instead of using an array for this can you not have a function that does this? Also, are you getting the `true`/`false` and `||` dynamically from the data? Because that is the only case I can think of in which you'd want to do what you are trying to do in your question, and even then it would be inefficient.

Comment: For context, why I want to do this: I am working on a PHP implementation of a query language. The booleans `true`, `false` and strings `||`, `&&` are returned by the parser, i.e. dynamically from the data. So I need to convert the array specifically to something useful. Which is also the reason why `implode`/`eval` is not an option, since the data is not sanitized.

Comment: @Ood Okay, I have to go right now, but tomorrow, I'll try to write an answer specifically designed for your problem, which is efficient and secure.